# checkbox inside div. On click checked or unchecked using jquery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked, unchecked

Hi i want to make checkbox checked or unchecked when i click div with text. Using jquery 1.9.1
here is a link to js fiddle

```
<div class="tel_show">
    <input type="checkbox" name="whatever" />
    &nbsp; visible
</div>

$("div.tel_show").live("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( checkbox.attr("checked") == "" ){
        checkbox.attr("checked","true");
    } else {
        checkbox.attr("checked","");
    }
});
```

[js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kagtJ/)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The use of `.live()` is deprecated on jQuery 1.9.x , also the use of `checked` html attribute to toggle checkboxes is deprecated, use `.prop('checked')` instead, your updated code should be:

```
$("div.tel_show").on("click",function(event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) return;

    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");

    if( !checkbox.prop("checked") ){
        checkbox.prop("checked",true);
    } else {
        checkbox.prop("checked",false);
    }
});
```

see [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kagtJ/1/)

Answer (score 4):

use .prop() instead of .attr() and .live() is removed in 1.9, use .on() instead

```
$(document).on("click", "div.tel_show", function (event) {
    var target = $(event.target);
    if (target.is('input:checkbox')) {
        return;
    }
    var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type='checkbox']");
    checkbox.prop("checked", !checkbox.is(':checked'));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JhEaJ/)