# Jquery method to capture checkbox click inside nested div

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, checkbox

```
<div class="panel-body" id="sell_in">
    @foreach (var state in Model.States)
    {
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedStates" id="buy_@state.Value" value="@state.Value" /> @state.Text
            </label>
         </div>
     }
</div>
```

I need to capture when any of the 50 checkboxes are checked.  This isn't doing it, and I expect it's because the checkboxes are nested in another `<div>` under `sell_in`.

```
$(document).on("click", "div.sell_in", function (event) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

(I got this solution from here: [checkbox inside div. On click checked or unchecked using jquery 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017802/checkbox-inside-div-on-click-checked-or-unchecked-using-jquery-1-9-1))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to select checkbox's using `input:checkbox` :

```
$(document).on("click", "input:checkbox", function (event) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Or specify the ones inside `div` using :

```
$(document).on("click", "div#div_id_here input:checkbox", function (event) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

Hoep this helps.

Comment: Ok, but I should have said... there are going to be two groups of check boxes, each with all 50 states.  One is sell_in,the other is buy_in.

Comment: Sure `"div#div_id_here input:checkbox"` check my update.

Comment: @iHasCodeForU the id is already unique. it's the id of the div outside of the loop. thanks for your intervention

Comment: No @iHasCodeForU no need for multiple event listner just reread the OP and the answer..

Comment: @iHasCodeForU, take abother look at the code.  The div with the id is OUTSIDE the foreach loop

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki, nailed it!  Thank you.  I will mark as answer in 7 minutes  when it lets me.

Comment: my bad, should have looked above the loop

Comment: @iHasCodeForU Use classes for styling and if really needed ids and data attributes to describe elements you can use as selectors in your scripts. You can for example use `data-id=""`to identify elements which represent the same component with the same identifiable attribute. If your CSS changes and classes are removed/added to change the UI the last thing you want is your functional code to break because of it. Best to keep those areas separated in my humble opinion.